# Inserting a draft reply into an open reply window in a Gmail Google Workspace Add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace-add-ons

I am making a Gmail Add-on that suggests a reply to an email in your inbox.

I am having trouble inserting the "suggestion" into the Gmail reply window.

I am inserting the suggestion using the [ComposeActionResponse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/compose-action-response) API. When a user clicks the "Use Suggestion" button, the following code runs:

```js
// Fetch the currently open Gmail message in the inbox
const message = getCurrentMessage(e)

// Create a draft reply based off the suggestion
const draft = message.createDraftReply(e.parameters.suggestion);

// Insert the draft
CardService.newComposeActionResponseBuilder().setGmailDraft(draft).build()
```

The draft is not being inserted into the open reply window (if it is open) when the user presses the "Use Suggestion" button. It is being inserted into the user's "Drafts". So they have to go into Drafts and click on the newly created Draft message. This is a bad user experience.

### Failure case

1. User clicks the reply button inside of a Gmail email which opens up the reply window on the left (see screenshot below).
2. User reads the "suggestion" provided by the Add-on and presses the USE SUGGESTION button in the add-on on the right.
3. The suggestion is inserted into `Drafts`. It **does not** appear in the open reply window.

[image]

### Success case

1. User opens an email and **does not** click the reply button inside of a Gmail email so the reply window is **not** open (see screenshot below).
2. User reads the "suggestion" provided by the Add-on and presses the USE SUGGESTION button in the add-on on the right.
3. The reply window inside of Gmail opens up and the suggestion is inserted into the reply window.

[image]

### Question

How can I get the suggestion to be inserted into an already opened reply window?

Answer (score 1):

From https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/gmail/compose

> If you want your add-on to alter a draft the user is currently viewing, [extend the compose UI](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/gmail/extending-compose-ui) instead.

From the link in the above quote, more specifically from https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/gmail/extending-compose-ui#example_2

> The following code snippet shows how to build a compose UI that
> inserts images into the current draft email.
>
> ```
> /**
>  * Compose trigger function that fires when the compose UI is
>  * requested. Builds and returns a compose UI for inserting images.
>  *
>  * @param {event} e The compose trigger event object. Not used in
>  *         this example.
>  * @return {Card[]}
>  */
> function getInsertImageComposeUI(e) {
>   return [buildImageComposeCard()];
> }
>
> /**
>  * Build a card to display images from a third-party source.
>  *
>  * @return {Card}
>  */
> function buildImageComposeCard() {
>   // Get a short list of image URLs to display in the UI.
>   // This function is not shown in this example.
>   var imageUrls = getImageUrls();
>
>   var card = CardService.newCardBuilder();
>   var cardSection = CardService.newCardSection().setHeader('My Images');
>   for (var i = 0; i < imageUrls.length; i++) {
>     var imageUrl = imageUrls[i];
>     cardSection.addWidget(
>         CardService.newImage()
>             .setImageUrl(imageUrl)
>             .setOnClickAction(CardService.newAction()
>                   .setFunctionName('applyInsertImageAction')
>                   .setParameters({'url' : imageUrl})));
>   }
>   return card.addSection(cardSection).build();
> }
>
> /**
>  * Adds an image to the current draft email when the image is clicked
>  * in the compose UI. The image is inserted at the current cursor
>  * location. If any content of the email draft is currently selected,
>  * it is deleted and replaced with the image.
>  *
>  * Note: This is not the compose action that builds a compose UI, but
>  * rather an action taken when the user interacts with the compose UI.
>  *
>  * @param {event} e The incoming event object.
>  * @return {UpdateDraftActionResponse}
>  */
> function applyInsertImageAction(e) {
>   var imageUrl = e.parameters.url;
>   var imageHtmlContent = '<img style=\"display: block\" src=\"'
>        + imageUrl + '\"/>';
>   var response = CardService.newUpdateDraftActionResponseBuilder()
>       .setUpdateDraftBodyAction(CardService.newUpdateDraftBodyAction()
>           .addUpdateContent(
>               imageHtmlContent,
>               CardService.ContentType.MUTABLE_HTML)
>           .setUpdateType(
>               CardService.UpdateDraftBodyType.IN_PLACE_INSERT))
>       .build();
>   return response;
> }
> ```

Comment: The `setUpdateDraftBodyAction()` API doesn't work in this case! If the user:
1. clicks the reply button inside of a Gmail email opening the reply window. And
2. presses the "USE SUGGESTION" button in the add-on on the right.
Then the suggestion is injected into Drafts, not the open reply window. This is true whether you use the `newUpdateDraftActionResponseBuilder().setUpdateDraftBodyAction ()` (what you suggested) or whether you use the `newComposeActionResponseBuilder().setGmailDraft(draft)` API (what I initially described). Is there a way to inject it into the open reply window? Thanks!

Comment: even if he extends the compose UI, how does he know the user has an existing compose UI open so he shouldn't render the "use suggestion" button in the side panel of the addon?